# Django OneToOne Fields to user ProgrammingError

Tags: python, django, django-models

I tried to add a ManyToManyField to user using a OneToOneField relation first. Here is my code:

```
ENTERPRISE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('a', "A"),
    ('b', "B"),
    ('c', "C"),
)

class Enterprise(models.Model):
    et_type = models.CharField(
        max_length = 10,
        choices=ENTERPRISE_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default='a'
        )
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    number = models.TextField(max_length=7)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s %s" % (self.et_type, self.name, self.number)

class Secretaire(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    workshop = models.ManyToManyField(Enterprise)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_secretaire(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Secretaire.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_secretaire(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Then in the python manage.py shell I try :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = User.objects.create(username="a", email="a@a.fr", password="a")
```

And it throw the error :

ProgrammingError: relation "helpdesk_secretaire" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "helpdesk_secretaire" ("user_id") VALUES (11) RE...

(The User is still created but no can't acces to user.secretaire, it throws the same error)

Do you have any clue about why I get this error?

Comment: sure you did makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: Did you make and run your migrations?

Comment: ...
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments on the original question: You need to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` first. The error message you are getting indicates that the table does not exist in the database.